# acroread only runs as root

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation, root, ldap

**Note** I already asked the exact same question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/974867/acroread-only-runs-as-root), with no success. I hope it's not a problem.

I am working on a computer connected to a LDAP server. The computer is running under Linux Mint 17. I installed `acroread` with

```
su root
add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
apt-get update
apt-get install acroread
```

When running `acroread` as root, everything is normal, Adobe Reader opens. When running as unpriviledged user, nothing happens, no error, no windows.

I tried

```
ps -e | grep acroread
```

to see if something was running but it did not return anything.

Would you have any ideas why this would happen? I guess it is due to the fact that I `/home` and `/share` are mounted from the LDAP server.

**Edit** This question was originally asked on superuser.SE. User @terdon asked me not to cross-post on several SE, so I copy the other answer I had on superuser.SE as it does not exactly answer the question but still, may be useful.

---

*Credits to PositronicBrain (superuser.SE user):*

First, open a command terminal and uninstall the acroread:

```
$ sudo apt-get --purge remove acroread
$ sudo apt-get --purge remove acroread-bin
```

(The package names can be obtained with this command: )

```
$ dpkg -l | grep -i acroread
```

Now, follow the instructions below to install Adobe Reader 9.5.5 2013, which is the latest version available for GNU/Linux from the Adobe website:

Download the installer:

```
$ wget -c ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/unix/9.x/9.5.5/enu/AdbeRdr9.5.5-1_i386linux_enu.deb
```

Use dpkg to install the package:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i AdbeRdr9.5.5-1_i386linux_enu.deb
```

Open the Adobe Reader and be happy:

```
$ acroread
```

(it works for 32-bit processors)

To uninstall:

```
$ sudo dpkg --purge adobereader-enu
```

Comment: I don't see why it should matter that `/home` and `/share` are remote mounts, but that doesn't mean Adobe hasn't assumed _something_. You could try running `strace acroread` to see if it starts but crashes. Oh. `mkdir /tmp/home; export OHOME="$HOME" HOME=/tmp/home; cp -a "$OHOME"/.??* /tmp/home; cd` then try running `acroread`

Comment: Please don't cross-post on multiple sites of the SE network. Choose one site and delete the question from the other. Otherwise, both could end up closed.

Comment: @terdon the OP asked their other instance of this question six weeks ago and got no satisfactory answers. It doesn't seem unreasonable to me that they should try elsewhere on SE?

Comment: @roaima it isn't which is why I haven't closed this. I am just suggesting that they delete one or the other. If they want to keep this one, then the one on [su] should be deleted.

Comment: @terdon: I'm not convinced by the relevance of your request (maybe a Meta post addresses this point?) but as a moderator, you must have good reasons for it. It deleted the other post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a) Stop using the old unix `acroread` as it probably hasn't seen [security updates](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvekey.cgi?keyword=acrobat) in years or b) use the `LD_PRELOAD` trick to fake out the `passwd` file open or c) manually add the necessary user accounts to the local `passwd` file.

I've had to install it on LDAPified machines, and it fails, and rummages through the `passwd` file:

```
$ strace -e trace=file -o ugh acroread

(acroread:17602): GLib-WARNING **: getpwuid_r(): failed due to unknown user id (1234)
...
$ grep passwd ugh
open("/etc/passwd", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/etc/passwd", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/etc/passwd", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
```

So one "fix" was indeed to add user entries to the `passwd` file.

Comment: +1 for the advice against `acroread`. The other things don't make much sense, though; it's not likely to be related to account issues. I've run `acroread` on LDAPified machines in the past, no problem.

Comment: you forgot `d) never, ever run programs like acroread as root.`

Comment: Thank you, this works! I'll come back and accept as soon as I understood why it worked. Just a note on why I need to use acroread: it's the only possibility under Linux, to my knowledge, to read animations in pdf (e.g. produced with beamer). I think everybody agrees there is a need for a alternate solution.

Comment: Could you explain `ugh` please?

Comment: @anderstood the man page for strace explains `-o filename` quite clearly

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem (acroreader runs only as root), on linux mate x64, with ldap.

Just installed libnss-ldap:i386 and it worked as ldap user with no problem.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/172946)

Comment: @countermode Maybe xKill edited his comment after your comment, but I think it answer the question (relevantly or not, that's another question and unfortunately, I cannot check it).

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem on Fedora 64 bits by installing the 32 bits sssd-client:

```
dnf install -y sssd-client.i686
```